# Для какого типа представления графа написан этот алгоритм (BFS)

Tags: c++, алгоритм

На [emaxx](http://www.e-maxx-ru.1gb.ru/algo/bfs) начал изучать алгоритмы. Дошел до графов. Подскажите пожалуйста, для какого типа представления графа написал алгоритм поиска в ширину в графе ?

`vector < vector<int> > g; // граф`

Список смежности или матрица смежности ?

и как нужно считывать матрицу или список смежности в этот вектор векторов ?

Comment: И где же сам алгоритм? И в чем отличие "таблицы смежности" от "матрицы смежности"? Что такое "таблица смежности" вообще?

Comment: @AnT алгоритм по ссылке. Таблица смежности - список смежности.

Comment: опечатка была в описании

Comment: список смежности - `g[i]` хранит в себе вектор (или список) вершин смежных с i-ой вершиной

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду в примере использования:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<g[v].size(); ++i) {
    int to = g[v][i];
```

g- список смежности. т.е. g[a] содержит массив номеров вершин, смежных с вершиной a.